# Replacing certain combination of characters

Tags: java, replaceall

I'm trying to remove the first bad characters (CAP letter + dot + Space) of this.

> A. Shipping Length of Unit
>   C. OVERALL HEIGHT
>   Overall Weigth
>   X. Max Cutting Height

I tried something like that, but it doesn't work:

```
string.replaceAll("[A-Z]+". ", "");
```

The result should look like this:

> Shipping Length of Unit
>   OVERALL HEIGHT
>   Overall Weigth
>   Max Cutting Height

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
string.replaceAll("^[A-Z]\\. ", "")
```

Examples

```
"A. Shipping Length of Unit".replaceAll("^[A-Z]\\. ", "")
// => "Shipping Length of Unit"
"Overall Weigth".replaceAll("^[A-Z]\\. ", "")
// => "Overall Weigth"
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I had more problems because the space was not an space, looked like but it wasn't and I took a lot of time to notice it

Answer (score 1):

```
input.replaceAll("[A-Z]\\.\\s", "");
```

**[A-Z]** matches an upper case character from A to Z

**\.** matches the dot character

**\s** matches any white space character

However, this will replace every character sequence that matches the pattern.
For matching a sequence at the beginning you should use

```
input.replaceAll("^[A-Z]\\.\\s", "");
```

Comment: You can add some explanations to what you did. Not everyone is skilled in regex. (Although that `{1}` in the string can be removed.)

Comment: Thanks, I've added some explanation and removed the {1}

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
myString.replaceAll("([A-Z]\\.\\s)","")
```

- [A-Z] : match a single character in the range between A and Z.
- \. : match the dot character.
- \s : match the space character.

Comment: Why do you replace the "cut content" with a single whitespace? And what do you think would happen if the file line would be "A. Result for B. should be C. " and is that what OP expects?

Comment: Oh, thats a typo. Thanks for notifying me. Regarding the B. should be C., you're right, I am going to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking your code it is hard to tell the problem. but from my experience this is the common problem which generally we make in our initial days:

```
String string = "A. Test String";
string.replaceAll("^[A-Z]\\. ", "");
System.out.println(string);
```

String is an **immutable** class in Java. what it means once you have create a object it can not be changed. so here when we do replaceAll in existing String it simply create a new String Object. that you need to assign to a new variable or overwrite existing value something like below :

```
String string = "A. Test String";
string  = string.replaceAll("^[A-Z]\\. ", "");
System.out.println(string);
```